# Right function for computing a limited number of eigenvectors of a complex symmetric matrix in Armadillo

Tags: c++, matlab, armadillo

I am using the Armadillo library to manually port a piece of Matlab code. The matlab code uses the eigs() function to find a small number (~3) of eigen vectors of a relative large(200x200) covariance matrix R. The code looks like this:

```
[E,D] = eigs(R,3,"lm");
```

In Armadillo there are two functions eigs_sym() and eigs_gen() however the former only support **real** symmetric matrix and the latter requires ARPACK (I'm building the code for Android). Is there a reason eigs_sym doesn't support complex matrices? Is there any other way to find the eigenvectors of a complex symmetric matrix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [eigs_sym()](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#eigs_sym) and [eigs_gen()](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#eigs_gen) functions (where the **s** in eig**s** stands for *sparse*) in Armadillo are for *large [sparse](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#SpMat)* matrices.  A "large" size in this context is roughly 5000x5000 or larger.

Your R matrix has a size of 200x200. This is very small by current standards. It would be much faster to simply use the dense eigendecomposition [eig_sym()](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#eig_sym) or [eig_gen()](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#eig_gen) functions to get all the eigenvalues / eigenvectors, followed by extracting a subset of them using [submatrix](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#submat) operations like `.tail_cols()`

Comment: I did try eig_sym() but it is much slower. In my code the decomposition sits inside two loops. For real matrices of 200x200 size there is a 5-6x slowdown if I compute all the eigen vectors.

Comment: Make sure you use a fast implementation of BLAS and LAPACK, like [OpenBLAS](http://www.openblas.net/), which should be available for ARM processors (commonly used for Android phones). This will make a massive difference in speed.

Comment: @farhanhubble You're concerned because the method gives you enough solutions is slower than the method which doesn't? I think this answer should be accepted if it addresses your actual issue, speed is not the problem you originally posed.

Comment: @mtall I'm already linking with OpenBlas and Clapack. All 200 eigenvectors are still slow to compute. I think looking under the hood of the Matlab implementation might offer some clues. Still not sure why complex sparse symmetric matrices are not supported by **eigs_sym() ** but that's a question for the Armadillo mailing list.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tested constructing a 400x400 real symmetric matrix by replacing each complex value, a+bi, by a 2x2 matrix [a,b;-b,a] (alternatively using a block variant of this)?

This should construct a real symmetric matrix that in some way correspond to the complex one.
There will be a slow-down due to the larger size, and all eigenvalues will be duplicated (which may slow down the algorithm), but it seems straightforward to test.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little bit how the eigenvectors of the matrix you're suggesting are related to the eigenvectors of the actual complex matrix?

Comment: IIRC instead of the complex eigenvector [z1;z2;...] there will be two real eigenvectors [Re(z1);-Im(z1);Re(z2);-Im(x2);...] and [Im(z1); Re(z1); Im(z2); Re(z2); ...] (but the eigenvalue is duplicated so there could be another linear combination).